# Disable hyperlink after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to disable a hyper link once it is clicked. I found a solution to use `onSubmit` function because this will allow the form to submit and then it disables the link immediately  but in here it is not doing so.

I've also written a `JavaScript` function but the problem is that how would I invoke this function after the button is clicked.

JS

```
 function disableLink() {
     if(document.getElementById('downloadReport').clicked = true) {
        document.getElementById('downloadReport').disabled = true;   
     }
 }
```

Form:

```
 <td class="dataFieldCell">
            <div class="esignNavigation">
                <s:if test="%{#parameters.showReport}">
                <a href="#x" id="downloadReport" style="width:155px" title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions." onSubmit="document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').disabled=true"><span>Export E-Sign Information</span></a> 
                </s:if>             
            </div> 
        </td>
```

Please let me know if anyone has done something similar to this.

Thanks.

Comment: This means JavaScript is the only solution for it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anchor element `a` is not a form element, so it will not trigger the `onsubmit` event.  You need to bind to the 'click' event and handle the click state yourself.  The 'disabled' attribute for anchor elements is not honored on all browsers, so you cannot rely on it for behavior or to change appearance.  You would need to add a class to the element and CSS for that class to make it appear disabled.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("download");
elem.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);

var download_clicked = false;
function myFunction(ev) {
  if(download_clicked) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    alert("One time!");
    download_clicked = true;
    elem.classList.add("disabled");
  }
}
```

```css
a.disabled {
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="download">This Works</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="download2" onclick='alert("Every Time!\ndisabled="+this.disabled);this.disabled=true;'>This doesn't</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class after submit:

```
.disabled-link{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

[Can i Use browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events%3A)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Michell. Is there a way to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: Will this take affect after the form is submitted?